# Internal search doesn't find questions when only part of tag is included

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, search

I've posted this question on meta.superuser before, but I was redirected here, as the search works the same on all sites:

---

I've checked a post on my phone, than tried to search for it in my pc, but didn't succeeded for first try:

[image]

After modification I've found it:

[image]

There was just a slight difference: first search term contained `Excel`. I'd expect superuser's search engine to find questions when search term only partially contains a tag name (e.g. `Excel` instead of `Microsoft-Excel` in this case).

Comment: The SE search system is unreliable. If I really need help, I just put it into Google and add `site:whatever.stackexchange.com`.